# ORA-01722 when retrieving Data from a View out of Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, oracle, view, crystal-reports

I built a view in SQLDeveloper on an Oracle database.

When I query the view it works without an error.

But when I query the view from Crystal Reports and try to retrieve data from a mixed calculation of `varchar2` fields (containing only numeric entries) and numbers it throws the following Error: 22018

> ORA-01722 Invalid Number

Table_A:

```
a Varchar2(20)
b Number
```

View:

```
SELECT a*b AS value_ab FROM TABLE A
```

Has anyone expirienced a similar issue? Changing the datatype is not an option. I also tried to convert the variable with "To_Number" but it didn't prevent the error from occuring.

Comment: How are you using the retrieved value - are you joining the view to something else? Are you adding filters when you query it directly or from the report? Are you retrieving all rows from the result set in SQL Developer or just seeing that it is OK for the first fetch? It's likely you do have a non-numeric value in your `varchar2` column and just don't always hit it.

Comment: What are your NLS settings in SQL Developer and from Crystal Reports, and are any of your string values floats? It's feasible you could have different NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS which would cause a string with a decimal separator to throw that error.

Comment: Different tables are joined to a view. the view contains some filters and the report contains additional filters. I also tried to put all filters into the view, or select the data (type Varchar2) out of a subselect. I have about 140 Records in the view, so i'm able to fetch all rows. I checked the records and they are all numeric.

Comment: But are they all integers, or do they have decimal separators? If they are floats, are they stored as `1.23` or `1,23`? The NLS settings will affect how the two are interpreted, and whether they can be converted.

Comment: They are all float values like `1.23`. Settings in SQL Developer (Decimal Seperator = '.'). I'm not sure if crystal has global settings for this, so I set the local computer settings to decimal seperator = . I tried the following as select-statemen (see example above) `5+'5.0' as calculated` an it also throws this error.

Comment: I doubt it would use that computer setting directly, it'll either be based one the overall locale or what the settings were when it was installed. That you had to change it is informative though. I believe you can explicitly set the NLS parameters for the DB connection but I don't use Crystal so I'm not sure exactly how/where. Relying on the client settings isn't ideal though (but neither is storing numbrs as strongs, of course). Are the numbers all in a similar format? If there is a format mask that would work for all values you can still handle it in the view.

Comment: Good point! I have a second installation of crystal via citrix. I tried to open the view out of this program and it worked. Next step will be to find out which settings I've to change on my local installation. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You are storing numbers as strings (which is always a bad idea but you've already said you can't change that), and from comments they are float values with a period as the decimal separator. Your SQL Developer NLS settings make an implicit conversion valid, but your Crystal Reports NLS settings do not - although probably inherited from the PC's locale at some level, the relevant part here is that `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` ends up as `',.'` from there, vs. `'.,'` in SQL Developer.

You can probably change the NLS settings for your installation of Crystal Reports - I don't use it so can't tell you exactly how - but you'll still be relying on anyone else querying your view also having the 'right' NLS settings, which is not always going to be under your control.

If the strings are always in a fairly standard format, with a maximum scale and precision, then you can change the view definition to include the knowledge of the decimal separator used in the string values.

Essentially when you do `a * b` you're doing an implicit conversion, and you can see an explicit conversion also fails, with `to_char(a) * b` or `cast(a as number) * b`. Without changing the NLS settings both will get the ORA-01722.

You can either convert using a fixed mask with a period separator:

```
select to_number(a, '999999.99') * b as value_ab from table_a;
```

Or use the more generic separator symbol `D` and override the NLS settings, which is probably overkill in this case as the separator is fixed:

```
select to_number(a, '999999D99', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=''.,''') * b
  as value_ab from table_a;
```

Either way you need to be able to specify the maximum number of digits you expect to see before and after the decimal separator, so you might need `9.99999` or `99999999.999` or some other variant - it depends entirely on your data.